# Create nested relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've been trying to discover whether or not it's currently possible to do the following.

Basically I have three models: `Customer`, `Invoice`, and `Unit`. *(`Customer` **has one** `Invoice`; an `Invoice` **has many** `Unit`s).*

I was wondering if it was possible to seamlessly do the following:

```php
...

# Let's pretend that further up the code that
# Customer has all the properties set and now
# being saved in the database.

$Customer->save();

# This is currently trying set the values of
# 'units' to a non-existent table column in 
# 'invoices' table.

$Customer->invoice()->create([
    "units" => [
        [
            "name" => "Unit 1",
            "amount" => 999.99,
            "tax" => "20%",
            "type" => "+"
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you setup the relationships in the model as you described them, then you can achieve it close to what you've shown. Something like this:

`Customer`

```
public function invoice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Invoice::class);
}
```

`Invoice`

```
public function units()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Unit::class);
}
```

Then calling:

```
$customer->invoice()->units()->create([
            "name" => "Unit 1",
            "amount" => 999.99,
            "tax" => "20%",
            "type" => "+"
        ]);
```

Should work.

Comment: Provided I `fresh` the model first to get the newly created invoice :)!

Comment: if you call save on the `invoice` first, then you should just call `$invoice->units()...` instead of doing it through the `Customer`. so `$invoice = $customer->invoice()->create(...);` before, and then add units.

Comment: Oh lovely, thank you @nakov. Setting as answer when the timer lets me :)!

Answer (score 0):

If you setup the relationships in the model as you described them, then you can achieve it close to what you've shown. Something like this:

**Customer**

```
public function invoice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Invoice::class);
}
```

**Invoice**

```
public function units()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Unit::class);
}
```

**Then calling:**

```
$customer->invoice()->units()->create([
    "name" => "Unit 1",
    "amount" => 999.99,
    "tax" => "20%",
    "type" => "+"
]);
```

Should work.

if you call save on the invoice first, then you should just call $invoice->units()

```
$invoice = $customer->invoice()->create([
    "campany" => "Unit 1",
    "dat" => "2022-02-18"
]);

$invoice->units()->create([
    "name" => "Unit 1",
    "amount" => 999.99,
    "tax" => "20%",
    "type" => "+"
]);
```

... instead of doing it through the Customer. so $invoice = $customer->invoice()->create(...); before, and then add units.